# Why is the cursor not at the expected position?

Tags: modeling, 3d-cursor

In this configuration, where the bottom edges of this object are at world origin coordinates (0,0,0), and this edge has a length of 0.196m, why is the cursor not at the expected position when I give it a 0,0,0.196 location?..

What's the right way to put the cursor where I want it to be?

[image]

[image]

Comment: is your model scaled? try going into object mode, apply any transforms and go back into edit mode (ctrl+a -> all transforms)

Comment: It was exactly the issue. I found it myself but the apply any transforms is a neat thing to know! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was simple enough: dimensions of the object have been manually changed, it messed with the scale of the object and Z scale value was a little bit under 1.0. Distances appear to be mesured before taking scale into account.

Comment: And the answer should have also an advice: Always, always, always - Apply scale of your objects.